# Numpy arrays of different dimension concatenate error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy

I have four Numpy arrays of shapes:

```
(2577, 42)
(2580, 100)
(2580, 236)
(2580, 8)
(2580, 37)
```

When I try to concatenate all of them do except (2577, 42). I get an error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 2580 and the array at index 4 has size 2577
```

The code I am using:

```
dataset = np.concatenate((onehot_b, num_v, onehot_s, onehot_c, onehot_s), axis=1)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What about adding three rows to the array that has 2577 rows with some nan values.

Comment: Concatenating four of those should work; it's the first that has the wrong dimensions to work on either axis.  Change that!

Answer (score 0):

The error is prety clear. You Cannot concatenate arrays of different sizes. One possible way out is convert the numpy arrays to lists and append all list lines to you dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not allow non-rectangular arrays, meaning that all sub-arrays should have the same dimension along the same axis. In your case, `2577` and `2580`, are dimensions along same `axis=0` that you are not stacking over (hence not adding them along that axis and they should have same length). If you can change all of them to have same first dimension shape, you can use concatenate. If you insist on stacking them, another way is just stacking arrays rather than their content:

```
dataset = np.asarray([onehot_b, num_v, onehot_s, onehot_c, onehot_s])
```

This will create an array of arrays for you.